# Columna dataframe según el máximo entre varias columnas (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Quiero encontrar la manera más sencilla de lograr la columna "Mejor jugador" la cual contiene el nombre del jugador con menor tiempo.
Tengo una manera poco practica de obtenerlo ya que el número de jugadores puede llegar hasta 5

El dataframe es df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jugador uno':["Juul","RGB10","Holi2","Combo"]\
               ,'Tiempo jug1':[13,21,15,4]\
               ,'Jugador dos':["Jar21","helen3","Dimi","kanh"]\
               ,'Tiempo jug2':[5,7,19,4]\
               ,'Jugador tres':["josi","Mae","Dylen","Joe18"]\
               ,'Tiempo jug3':[4,12,8,66,]
              })
```

Y la forma en que obtengo el nombre del mejor jugador es esta:

```
df["Mejor jugador"]=np.where((df[['Tiempo jug1', 'Tiempo jug2','Tiempo jug3']].min(axis=1))==df["Tiempo jug1"]\
    ,df["Jugador uno"]\
    ,np.where( (df[['Tiempo jug1', 'Tiempo jug2','Tiempo jug3']].min(axis=1))==df["Tiempo jug2"]\
              ,df["Jugador dos"]\
              ,df["Jugador tres"]\
             )\
    )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
df

Answer (score 0):

Las columnas "Jugador" están representando partidas realizadas?

Que tal unificando bajo un mismo par de columnas y luego ordenando. Algo así:

```
import pandas as pd

#Modificando el DataFrame original
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jugadores':["Juul","RGB10","Holi2","Combo","Jar21","helen3","Dimi","kanh","josi","Mae","Dylen","Joe18"]\
               ,'Tiempos':[13,21,15,4,5,7,19,4,4,12,8,66,]
              })

df.sort_values('Tiempos')
```

Si tomas los datos de alguna fuente/archivo en particular; coméntame y reajusto el código.

Comment: Cada fila es una partida, la fuente son csv en los que no se sabe cuantos jugadores habrá, es decir que pueden haber hasta 5 jugadores y a cada csv se les debe asignar la columna "Mejor jugador". No se pueden consolidar ya que los nombres de los encabezados pueden cambiar, además de que cada csv corresponde a partidas de una naturaleza totalmente distinta. El objetivo es lograr la columna "Mejor jugador" de una manera más reducida en cuanto a caracteres en código